# Need help regarding information retrieval

Tags: java, algorithm, search-engine, information-retrieval

I am working on a search engine and need help in ranking web pages. I have made a database table in which I am storing words, link number and frequency. Frequency will tell how many words appear in that particular link.

Now I want to rank every page according to the provided query and display link on screen, which Algorithm will help me? need implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simplified solution is using the **[tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) score**:

```
tf(t,d) = (1/2 * #occurances(t,d)) / max{ #occurances(w,d) | for all w in collection }
```

This is basically the number of occurances of the term in the document, normalized.

```
idf(t,D) = log( #documents / #documents_t_appears_in)
```

And the tf-idf score is then denoted as:

```
tf_idf(t,d) = tf(t,d) * idf(t,D)
```

The idea is - boost document that contains the term a lot of times, however - if the term is very common - make it less significant - since if it appears in most documents - it doesn't say much about the relevance of the document. (but if the term is rare - boost it, it is very informative).

If your query is `q=t1,t2,t3,..,tk`, the total score of the query is:

```
tf-idf(q,d) = td-idf(t1,d) * tf-idf(t2,d) * ... * tf-idf(tk,d)
```

You can combine this method with any link analysis method such as [Page-Rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank).

As a side note, there is a java open-source search engine library called [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/), that do a lot of the dirty work for you.

Comment: this is helpful! you are saying that for each query and in that qyery for each word i should calculate tf-idf right ? I am little bit confuse that if tf-idf for certain query give me a result then how will i compare that result to rank a page? let say a query has three different words and i will calculate three different tf-idf and now i will rank that page on top according to max value of tf-idf is that so ? tf-idf is caluculated on runtime when user enters a query? Thanks !

Comment: @user3738548 tf-idf gives a rank for how similar a page (document) is for a query. The higher the td-idf score, the better you should rank this document. And yes, tf-idf is calculated on run-time.

Comment: This means there is no need to calculate intersection(AND operation) of document ID's (Document Number) for multiple word query right? and i can directly calculate Tf-idf for each word in a query and rank that document is that so?

Comment: @user3738548 Usually, a boolean model is first used to find all candidates, and you rank only the documents that were found in the interserction, because it is much more efficient. The [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) (which is also used for intersection calculation) can hold #occurances(t,d) for each term and document, and you need a simple hashmap to map from each term to the total number of occurances this term appears in the entire collection.

Comment: need a little help, now i want to run my application with tomcat server, but facing this error "FAIL-Application at context path /my_app could not be started" ...

Comment: link to files: web.xml [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5q4t0oyeecnowf/web.xml), test.jsp [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbrqi9grpa3hbo3/test.jsp), index1.jsp [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/wrko89bvw7aek88/index1.jsp), final.jsp [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4ltwewrb8okk6l/final.jsp